# Converter Parameter In ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, enums

I have a collection of Checkboxes in a Listbox binding to an Enum which uses a converter. Code shown below:

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="183" Margin="159,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="144">
  <ListBox.Resources>
    <local:FlagsEnumValueConverter x:Key="FlagsConverter" />
  </ListBox.Resources>
  <CheckBox Content="Checkbox1" IsChecked="{
    Binding Path=TestModel.TestEnum, 
    Converter={StaticResource FlagsConverter}, 
    ConverterParameter={x:Static tc:TestEnum.Test1}}"/>
  <CheckBox Content="Checkbox2" IsChecked="{
    Binding Path=TestModel.TestEnum, 
    Converter={StaticResource FlagsConverter}, 
    ConverterParameter={x:Static tc:TestEnum.Test2}}"/>
  <CheckBox Content="Checkbox3" IsChecked="{
    Binding Path=TestModel.TestEnum, 
    Converter={StaticResource FlagsConverter}, 
    ConverterParameter={x:Static tc:TestEnum.Test3}}"/>
</ListBox>
```

Converter Code:

```
class FlagsEnumValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private int mTargetValue;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var mask = (int)parameter;
        mTargetValue = (int)value;
        return ((mask & mTargetValue) != 0);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        mTargetValue ^= (int)parameter;
        return Enum.Parse(targetType, mTargetValue.ToString());
    }
}
```

I'd rather use an ItemTemplate to keep things clean and simple however I'm not sure what to do with the 'ConverterParameter' since it requires the specific Enum value. I've been Googling for a solution but haven't found one. I honestly don't even know where to start. Is this even possible?

Comment: Are you running this in WPF? Xamarin? I am guessing WPF. If so, you may want to take a look at `MultiBinding` and a multi-value converter. Then you would not need to use the `ConverterParameter`

Comment: If you want to keep things clean and simple you could move the logic to the `ViewModel`, ie `TestModel` in your case. Add a boolean property for every flag and bind those to the view. Inside the boolean property you then add/remove the flag from TestEnum.